# Ошибка в написании условия

Tags: python, pandas

Я совсем не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы условие проверяло линии csv файла, а потом проверяло на наличие. То есть я ввожу текст, который есть в файле, но текст скрипт не находит, поэтому создаёт новый. Помогите пожалуйста, да укажите, где я совершил ошибку в файле.

Вот код:

```
import pandas as pd


word = input("")


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "word": word,
}, index=[0])

file = open("Lina.csv", "r")
fileline = file.readlines()
if word == fileline:
    print("true")
else:
    df.to_csv("Lina.csv", mode="a", index=False, header=False)
logs = pd.read_csv('Lina.csv')
print(logs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что функция [`readlines`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/file.readlines/) выводит не текст, а список, каждый из элементов которого есть строка текста. Стоит также учесть, что каждая такая строка оканчивается на `\n`.

Например, пусть в `Lina.csv` лежит строка "`"hi`", тогда `file.readlines() => ['hi\n']`.

Поэтому, чтобы прочесть определённое слово (если оно такое в файле единственное), нужно напрямую взять его из списка (нулевой индекс), а затем обрезать строку от `\n` с помощью `strip()`.

```py
if word == fileline[0].strip('\n'): # вместо word == fileline
    print("true")
```

Если же введённая Вами строка действительно равна строке из csv-файла, то выведется `true` + не будет дополнительной записи в csv-файл.

В том случае, если имеется строка с несколькими словами (или несколько слов), можно прочесть каждую строку по отдельности, а затем, если считать, что слова разделяются запятыми (типичино для csv-файлов), вывести `true`, иначе добавить данный элемент. Это легко делается при помощи конструкции [`for-in-else`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/for-in-else/).

```py
import pandas as pd

word = input("")

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "word": word,
}, index=[0])

file = open("Lina.csv", "r")
filelines = file.readlines()
for fileline in filelines:
    if word in fileline.strip('\n').split(','):
        print("true")
        break
else:
    df.to_csv("Lina.csv", mode="a", index=False, header=False)
logs = pd.read_csv('Lina.csv')
print(logs)
```

Comment: Всё верно, выводится, но что если элементов в коде несколько и среди них нужно найти определённый элемент?

Comment: Определённый элемент какой — первый, последний или же любой по желанию?

Comment: Элемент - который подходит к переменной word.

Comment: @Артем Голубев - а то-же самое, но в общепринятых терминах можно? Что такое "элемент, который подходит к переменной"? Как вы определяете "подходящесть"? И зачем вы ввод пользователя упрятываете в Датафрейм? Если там все равно единственное значение храниться и никак не изменяется в самом коде?

Comment: И еще вопрос -  как вы собрались писать to_csv, если вы открыли файл с указанием метода "r"

Comment: Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда вписывается допустим слово "hi", то происходила проверка: есть ли слово в Lina.csv. Если есть, то выводит true, если нету, то записывает